# Several pending transactions to the same address - what happens?

Tags: transactions, gas, uniswap, pending-transactions, coinbase

I am trying to sell all my Shiba tokens from my Coinbase wallet (to Ethereum). I tried converting it through Uniswap, but nothing seemed to happen. So I did it again. And then through Sushiswap. I thought that there was a mistake since nothing seemed to happen, but I can now see on Etherscan that I have 3 pending transactions. Am I going to pay the gas fees for all these transactions? Is it normal that they are pending for several hours?

Comment: SAME problem here...and i kept increasing the gas fees which only made things worse

Answer (score 1):

You did not post a link to your address so it is difficult to pinpoint the exact cause. However, you most likely sent your first swap with a gas price that was too low.

Because of that, it has not yet been picked up by the miners. Any subsequent transaction will also be stalled regardless of their gas price (transactions are always processed in order).

Comment: The first one had a gas fee of 32$ and the last transaction of 75$. What can I do now to convert the coins?

Comment: You have to replace the transaction with one that has a higher gas price. How to do it depend on the wallet you use, so google it and you should find your answer.

Comment: I tried manually setting the nonce to 1 and make a transaction to my self. Now that transaction is also pending with a nonce of 6 (even though I know it was set to 1 when I made the transaction).